# PHP missing mb_strpos function?

Tags: php, apache

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_strpos() in /my/file.php
```

Which is odd because [`mb_strpos()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) was introduced in PHP 4, and I'm running PHP 5.3.3

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2012 19:38:14) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Anybody else run into something like this and know how to fix it? I searched and I can't figure it out.

PS. I'm running centOS 5.

Comment: (Maybe it was built without unicode/multibyte support?)

Comment: Did you include the mbstring extension? What does ``phpinfo()`` say? Have a look at http://ch2.php.net/mbstring for more information.

Comment: Are you in a namespace? You might have to prefix the function with a \.

Comment: To wit, the mbstring extension is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

MBString is not a default extension in PHP and you have to install it 
if you are running linux try

```
yum install  php-mbstring.x86_64 # for RedHat derivative systems
```

as a root user 
or

```
apt-get install php-mbstring.x86_64 # for Debian derivative systems
```

on windows you have to edit php.ini to use the extension dll library

**Note: mb_strpos still supported in PHP 5**

Comment: -1 , you are assuming that everyone uses same distro as you do

Comment: you should be a bit more specific about "linux" - there are a dozen linux-distributions out there and only few are using `yum` as rpm-package-manager - on ubuntu. for example, this would be `agt-get`. | EDIT: and one shall not "!!!!111oneeleven" as it's rude and boyish.

Comment: ya you are right but the reader should distinguish and should be smart to adapt the solution to meet his needs

Comment: the reader should be smart enought to look up the documentation, too. if you debate like this, stackoverflow is completely needless.

Comment: I had to install `php53-mbstring.x86_64`, but this was the most helpful answer. now quit fighting and take out your nerd-rage elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find out which PHP your server is using by placing a **info.php** with this code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then you need to download php-mbstring for this version, e.g. if you have PHP 8.0.15 then you need to install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mbstring
```

Then restart the apache2 service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your version of PHP wasn't built with the "--enable-mbstring" option.

You can check with the `phpinfo()` function. There should be a "mbstring" section. Mine has this:

```
mbstring

Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

sounds like it's simply not installed. please take a look at [the documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php):

> mbstring is a non-default extension. This means it is not enabled by default. You must explicitly enable the module with the configure option. [...]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cPanel and have access to your WHM panel then you need to enable **mbstring** PHP Extension from your EasyApache 4.

Just go top **WHM Home** » **EasyApache 4** » **Customize**

The search for **mbstring** under PHP Extensions and enable that as per your PHP versions (php80-php-mbstring).

For me it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

This is a basic [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) function. 
It seems your web host does not have the mbstring PHP extension installed.
Check your phpinfo(); and look for mbstring in it.