# installation Issue with phpmyadmin

Tags: php

I"ve tried everything to solve my issue of getting phpmyadmin to work on my kali linux 2020 using firefox.

In the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` I added:

```
<Directory usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
</Directory>

Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

but still doesn't work.

when i go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` all I get is a blank page.
I went into `/var/log/apache2/` to see if something shows up there that sheds light on the problem.

```
HP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PhpMyAdmin\\mb_strpos() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:253\nStack trace:
n#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(206): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getArgSeparator()
n#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(169): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getCommonRaw(Array, '?')
\n#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(749): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getCommon(Array)
\n#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(330): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::linkURL('https://secure....')
\n#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(353): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::getPHPDocLink('book.mbstring.p...') 
\n#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(973): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::warnMissingExtension('mbstring')
\n#6 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(106): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::checkExtensions()
\n#7 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(27): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...')
\n#8 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 253
```

(**sorry for the long post but I couldn't find a place on here where I can upload my log file.)

I don't really know where to start.

i have php version 7.4.6
Apache 2 Server version: Apache/2.4.43 (Debian)
Server built:   2020-03-31T06:02:12
and mysql installed. 
My kali is the latest version, 2020

any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692157/php-missing-mb-strpos-function

Comment: If John's recommendation does not work, try `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` and then try visiting `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: i looked at my phpinfo() file and I don't see mbstring section on there.  I can't find an answer on how I would put it on there

Comment: when I try sudo apt-get install php-mbstring it says:

hp-mbstring is already the newest version (2:7.4+76+0~20200511.26+debian10~1.gbpc9beb6).

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have Ubuntu 20.04, apache, tried with PHP versions 7.4, 7.3 and 7.2. Nothing seems to fix this. seems like none have this problem ? or a solution

Comment: I am facing the same problem but for my case it's at nginx server.

Comment: I am facing same issue too, have anyone fined out solutions?