# How to fix phpmyadmin - gives error after php upgrade?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

My system is MX-Linux 21/64 bits. After upgrade php7.4 to 8.1 myphpadmin stopped working. Shows blank page and after I cheked the error log of the apache2 I saw that error:

`[Thu Jul 13 00:05:25.647833 2023] [php:error] [pid 1231] [client 127.0.0.1:48414] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PhpMyAdmin\\mb_strpos() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:257\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(208): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getArgSeparator()\n#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(171): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getCommonRaw()\n#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(765): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getCommon()\n#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(338): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::linkURL()\n#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(367): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::getPHPDocLink()\n#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(995): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::warnMissingExtension()\n#6 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(110): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::checkExtensions()\n#7 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(23): require_once('...')\n#8 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 257`

I have purged and reinstalled php8.1, installed also 7.4 and reinstalled phpmyadmin. When I installed phpmyadmin I noticed that php8.2 installed automatically. I have searched the net for similar issues, but couldn't find any working solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP missing mb\_strpos function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692157/php-missing-mb-strpos-function)

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: I use ver. 5.0.4deb2+deb11u1

Answer (score 0):

If you install new version of php you must to install packages you need for project. Multibyte string function library it's not standard function that's why you need to install mbstring package

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php8.2-mbstring
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install php8.2-mbstring returns the follow:

php8.2-mbstring is already the newest version (8.2.7-1+0~20230609.23+debian11~1.gbp21561a).

Comment: Same:   php-mbstring is already the newest version (2:8.2+93+0~20230409.46+debian11~1.gbpdb4dcc).

Comment: After I succeed to install mdstring  phpmyadmin does not start again. Now the error log have changed to that: [error log](https://pastebin.com/saLNxB4T)

Comment: For now you need to enable binnary logging (it's your second line of log) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682381/how-do-i-enable-mysql-binary-logging and you need to change chmod for phpmyadmin config-db.cng file. Logs not complicatet, just do from line to line